# How to unload DOTS

Tags: xpages

Domino OSGi Tasklet Service will be important in the future to develop Java based tasklets to run on the Domino servers.
When I read the documentation from OpenNTF I see a command to load the DOTS framework by 'load dots'.
Everything runs fine, also my own tasklets.
But is there also a command to unload or stop the DOTS framework??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common syntax to quit a task is to issue "tell [task] quit" command, so "tell dots quit" should work.

Comment: If everything was that simple ;-)

Comment: It's also documented in the readme together with all other commands and parameters, e.g. DOTS profiles.

Comment: niklas, thanx. I just noticed that there are more pages in the readme ;-)